# Passing list as a parameter in url routing in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a Business model in Django where I need to insert information from an API. However, I want to avoid the duplicates in the database. So, whenever user clicks on a specific link of business I need to check if it already exists on database and if not I have to insert it into the database and view the result. Following code is what I have done so far.

```
def checkBusiness(request, business):
    try:
        result = Business.objects.get(checkId=business.checkId)

    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        b = Business(name=business[0]['name'], street_address=business[0]['location']['address'], city=business[0]['location']['city'], state=business[0]['location']['state'], country=business[0]['location']['country'], category=business[0]['categories']['name'], distance=business[0]['location']['distance'], checkId=business[0]['id'])
        b.save()
        result = Business.objects.get(checkId=checkId)

    context = {
        'business': result,
    }

    return render(request, "MyDiary/checkBusiness.html", context)
```

Here is how my routing looks like:

```
path('checkBusiness', views.checkBusiness, name='checkBusiness'),
```

And this is my html:

```
       {% for business in businesses %}
             <li>
                    /*business is a json file for specific business detail*/
                    <a href="{% url 'checkBusiness' business %}" > {{ business.name }}, {{ business.location.address }}, {{ business.location.postalCode }} </a>
             </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why don't you send the `id` of business instead?

Comment: if I send the id and if a business with that id is not in the database, I need to insert the business to database so I need to pass the business detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an object in a URL. You should understand that when you do `{% url something %}` you're just creating a url, the one you see in the address bar of your browser (the **path** part to be precise). A URL path does not contain objects, it's just a number of path segments separated by `/`, e.g. `/businesses/` or `/businesses/49` or `businesses/49/employees/`.

A URL may contain a **query string** after the **path**, which is a list of key/values after the `?`, e.g. `/businesses/?type=industrial&size=500`. In a Django view that responds to the URL `/businesses/`, you'll see that `request.GET` will have the key/value pairs `{"type": "industrial", "size": 500}`. To construct such a URL in a template you just append the parameters to the URL string:

```
"{% url 'business_list' %}?type={{ business.type }}&size={{ business.size }}"
```

The urls.py is just the list of **paths**, it doesn't take into account the **query string**. If you have a view for the path `/businesses/`, then it will accept **any** query string (which again, will be in `request.GET`).

But you should **never** write to the database on a GET request, so passing parameters like this to create a new record in the database is big no-no.

You should create a `<form method="post">` with method POST that submits the information to your view (in `request.POST`) and upon validation your view creates the record in the database. It can also check if the record already exists.

(Note that just checking with a `checkId` doesn't help much, since it's easy for anyone to just change the id so that the same business would still be duplicated in your database, just with a different id.)